# A polytime language with no subsets of lesser time complexity

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity, formal-languages

For any integer $l>0$  does there always exist a language with time complexity of order $O(n^l)$ such that it has no subsets of a lesser time complexity
ie $O(n^m)$ for any $m< l$.

We talk of infinite subsets here.

Q2  Do we have any polytime language with no non trivial superset of a lesser time complexity.